# Find and select multiple rows across workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I've Excel 2013 workbook containing 100+ sheets, I'm trying to find specific value and select multiple rows across workbook containing that value and then insert a row to be able to enter data across sheets as a group.

Currently I'm working on following VBA code but I'm stuck at error "Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument" against this line:     addSelection = Mid(addSelection, 1, Len(addSelection) - 1).

```
Public Sub SelectMultiple()
    Dim wbkthis As Workbook
    Dim shtthis As Worksheet
    Dim rngThis As Range
    Dim rngFind As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String
    Dim addSelection As String


    Set wbkthis = ThisWorkbook
    Set shtthis = wbkthis.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    // Set our range to search
    Set rngThis = shtthis.Range("B2", "B10")

    // Loop through it
    With rngThis

        // Find our required text
        Set rngFind = .Find("Jack")

        // If we find it then...
        If Not rngFind Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = rngFind.Address // Take a note of where we first found it
            addSelection = addSelection & rngFind.Address & "," // Add the cell's range to our selection

            // Loop through the rest of our range and find any other instances.
            Do
                Set rngFind = .FindNext(rngFind)
                addSelection = addSelection & rngFind.Address & ","
            Loop While Not rngFind Is Nothing And rngFind.Address <> firstAddress

        End If
    End With

    // Trim the last comma from our string
    addSelection = Mid(addSelection, 1, Len(addSelection) - 1)
    shtthis.Range(addSelection).Rows.Select // Select our rows!

    Set rngThis = Nothing
    Set shtthis = Nothing
    Set wbkthis = Nothing

End Sub
```

Thanks for your help in accomplishing above task.

Leo

Comment: Before running this line (trimming last comma), what does addSelection return? (you can check for example by inserting `msgbox(addSelection)` or `debug.print(addSelection)` before this line.

Comment: It's blank returns "

"

Comment: Ok, check my answer, hope it works. By the way, do you have "Jack" in your range?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the error you mentioned, code is running fine for me. Can you share your file?

Answer (score 0):

Ok you need to check first whether the String is empty or not.

```
If len(addSelection) > 0 then
    addSelection = left(addSelection, Len(addSelection) - 1)
    shtthis.Range(addSelection).EntireRow.Select
End if
```

I also replaced your mid() function, because I thought left() is easier, but your mid function should work just as well.

Comment: I'm getting compile error: Variable required - can't assign to this expression

Comment: also just used left() instead of mid() but still getting the same error, would appreciate if you could run the code at your machine. Just to check if issue isn't limited to me. Thanks!

Comment: Now its working but still doesn't select "entire rows", secondly how to extend it to work on other worksheet as well and also insert a row ultimately.

Comment: try `.EntireRow.Select`. As for the worksheets, you need a for-loop around the whole code, such as `for each ws in wkbthis.worksheets` & `next ws`. This would loop through all the worksheets in your workbook.

Comment: Do you want it for all sheets? You said you have 100+? or how are the sheet named? Sheet1, Sheet2, ...., Sheet100?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure whether you can select different ranges across worksheets at the same time... Is "Jack" always in B2, on all sheets? Also, I do not quite understand where you want to insert a row?

Comment: "Jack" is present in column B across all sheets what are named Sheet1, Sheet2...Sheet100. I want to select entire rows across these sheets and insert blank row using Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown.

Comment: Is it not possible, seems a simple task though. May be I've reached dead end?

Comment: How about you insert the row each time you find "Jack" in a sheet, instead of finding all first and then insert? Is it crucial for it to be selected? Or do you just need that extra row below "Jack" in each of your 100 sheets?

Comment: Yes it is, actually I'll be changes data in adjacent cells from time to time and some times I'll have to insert row above or below the selected rows to add new set of data. Would appreciate if you could suggest code for this.

Comment: I'll give it a try when I have access to a PC again

Comment: @LEO so I gave it a try, but you cannot select different ranges on different sheets at the same time, not even with VBA. If you know what changes you want to perform in the rows that you add, you could programm it into your code, instead of doing it manually, and have it run as soon as you find "Jack" in a sheet and add that row.

Comment: i had this idea in back of my mind, also I'm regularly hitting dead ends like this with coding scenarios too often and its not like I try to accomplish some outlandish feat. Anyway, Thanks!